# Open subpage with delay

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a web page for my self. I have a welcome screen with big background wallpaper and just one link that you have to click to get to the index page. I have a sound on welcome page that plays when link is clicked, but as soon as the link is clicked it opens index page so the sound is not even heard. I want to make few seconds delay after the link is clicked so that the sound can play first to the end.

My jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cs6yqawr/.

```
$('a[href*="/*html"]').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        (function(h) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location = h;
            }, 5000);
        })(this.href);
    });
});
```

Tried this code but I can't get it working.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried and it'll play music before to new page.

```
$('.big-btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this);
    var embed = $('<embed src="Kalimba.mp3" hidden="true">');
    embed.appendTo($('#embed'));
    embed.ready(function () {
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = 'index.html';
      }, 2000);

    });

});
```

You should replace my test mp3, target location, and delay ms for your usage.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just the selector on your event handler. Try:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function(h) {
        window.location = h;
    }, 5000, this.href);
});
```

Or ideally just give the link an id and bind the handler to that.

Comment: Tried this, after I click the link it opens instantly, the sound does not play and there is no delay. What am I doing wrong then?